# How can i hide a div class when another one has content

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm facing a problem with swiper slider and a pagination i'd like to hide if there is content in the caption div.

I created a http://jsfiddle.net/1sta65uv/2/ and did some reasearch about it, but i have no approach so far. I know that i'd need an if statement but how do i get the connection to the length?

Maybe you can help me a bit? Would be great

```
<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300">
      <div class="caption">Image caption</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300">
      <div class="caption"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300">
      <div class="caption">Image caption</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300">
      <div class="caption"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  <!-- Add Arrows -->
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
```

edit:

I would like to hide the pagination when  has content. the problem - it is for a dynamic page.

which means

slide 1 has pagination
slide 2 pagination hidden
slide 3 has pagination
slide 4 pagination hidden

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want to hide

Comment: Hi, i'd like to hide 

      <div class="caption"></div>

when it has content

Answer (score 2):

on each swipe you could fire:

```
if($('.swiper-slide-active').find('.caption').html() != '') {
    $('.swiper-pagination').css('visibility', 'hidden');
} else {
    $('.swiper-pagination').css('visibility', 'initial');
}
```

EDIT - I thought you wanted to hide the pagination in cases where the caption has content, but it seems you actually just want to hide all the captions. If that's the case, you could do this after you initialize the swiper:

```
$('.caption').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Or even:

```
$('.caption').html('');
```

UPDATE - If you only want to hide captions that have content, you can do:

```
$('.caption').each(function() {
    if ($(this).html() == '') {
        $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
});
```

Comment: How do i have to implement .each() ?
when i put your code all caption classes are hidden

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate whether the 'div.caption' has html inside it or just assign a class to the div where there is content. Example:

```
    <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300">
      <div class="caption captionContent">Image caption</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300">
      <div class="caption"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300">
      <div class="caption captionContent">Image caption</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300">
      <div class="caption"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  <!-- Add Arrows -->
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
```

then use jQuery like this:

```
    //some event {
    if($('.caption').hasClass('.captionContent')){
        $(this).hide();
    }
}
```

I hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Edit your .js file to

```
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
      pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
      paginationType: 'fraction'
    });

    swiper.on('slideChangeStart', function () {
    flag=$('.swiper-slide-active>.caption').html();
    if(flag!= "") {   
  $('.swiper-pagination').css('visibility', 'hidden');
} else {    
  $('.swiper-pagination').css('visibility', 'initial');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, this one made it work. Additionally i need to update the slider after initialization

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
  pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
  paginationType: 'fraction',
  'onInit': function() {
    flag = $('.swiper-slide-active>.caption').html();
    if (flag != "") {
      $('.swiper-pagination').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    } else {
      $('.swiper-pagination').css('visibility', 'initial');
    }
  }
});

swiper.on('slideChangeStart', function() {
  flag = $('.swiper-slide-active>.caption').html();
  if (flag != "") {
    $('.swiper-pagination').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  } else {
    $('.swiper-pagination').css('visibility', 'initial');
  }
});
```